# Source a bash file with functions in another directory errors with 'command not found'

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a directory similar to this:

```
.
|__ main
    |__ app
    |   |__ master_script.sh
    |   |__ master_parameters.sh
    |
|__ submodule
    |__ script.sh
    |__ parameters.sh
    |__ functions.sh
```

I want to run `master_script.sh`, which uses `source` to set a number of variables with `master_parameters.sh`.

`master_script.sh` then calls `script.sh`, which also uses `source` on `parameters.sh` and `functions.sh`. However when I do this, none of the variables in `parameters.sh` nor the functions in `functions.sh` seem to be set.

So when `script.sh` tries to use one of the functions, I get the error 'command not found'

i.e:

parameters.sh

```
my_foo="another thing"
```

functions.sh

```
functions do_task {
  echo "task done"
}
```

script.sh

```
do_task
```

master_parameters.sh

```
submodule_path=$(realpath "../../submodule")
my_foo="something"
```

master_script.sh

```
source master_parameters
cd $submodule_path
source parameters.sh
source functions.sh
./script.sh
```

Here when `master_script.sh` executes `./script.sh`, it won't find the function `do_task` since it hasn't been correctly sourced.

From looking around there seems to be something about sourcing in different directories? I've tried to use absolute pathing but that hasn't fixed the issue. Any idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `./script.sh` to call the script you want to use the imported functions but that doesn't work, when we call it with `./script.sh` it creates a new bash session that doesn't contain the imported functions, to fix this just use `source script.sh` or `. script.sh`, this way it will use the same shell session and keep the functions and variables imported from the other files.

Comment: Thank you, this actually did the trick for me :) I didn't realise I was creating a new bash session

Answer (score 2):

Facts:

- Variables are not exported by default.

  - Can be exported with `export`.
- Functions are not exported by default.

  - Can be exported **in Bash to Bash** with `export -f`.
- Child process inherits exported environment (simplification).

> how to get around this?

Export the function. `export -f do_task` before running `./script.sh`.

Source the `./script.sh`, so it inherits the whole current execution environment. To not affect current shell, run it in a subshell. `( source ./script.sh )`.

---

Note that `source file` searches for the file in `PATH`. Use `source ./file` to source from current working directory, the same way running `./prog` differs from running `prog` on command line.

Subjectively, prefer `do_task() {` over `function do_task {`, unlesss you really want to be compatible with ksh.

Comment: "Note that `source file` searches for the file in **PATH**" -- this is the key of this answer, I think. This has bitten me in the past.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can the entire file not be exported at once? Is doing so the same as to 'source' the file?

Comment: `can the entire file not be exported at once?` "files" can't be "exported", files can be read. I do not know what "export at once" means. Exported can be variables - additionally, in bash functions can also be exported.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases I suggest you to translate the relative path to semi-absolute path by the following approach:

```bash
script_abs_path=$(readlink -f $(dirname $0))
source ${script_abs_path}/submodule/script.sh
```

Comment: What is  semi-absolute path and how this will work?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo! I just fixed it. Thank you!